# How to access a column of grouped data to perform linear regression in pandas?

Tags: pandas-groupby, linear-regression

I want to perform a linear regression on groupes of grouped data frame in pandas. The function I am calling throws a KeyError that I cannot resolve.

I have an environmental data set called dat that includes concentration data of a chemical in different tree species of various age classes in different country sites over the course of several time steps. I now want to do a regression of concentration over time steps within each group of (site, species, age).

This is my code:

````
```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

dat = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

dat.head(15)

       SampleName  Concentration     Site Species  Age  Time_steps
0      batch1           2.18      Germany    pine    1           1
1      batch2           5.19      Germany    pine    1           2
2      batch3          11.52      Germany    pine    1           3
3      batch4          16.64       Norway  spruce    0           1
4      batch5          25.30       Norway  spruce    0           2
5      batch6          31.20       Norway  spruce    0           3
6      batch7          12.63       Norway  spruce    1           1
7      batch8          18.70       Norway  spruce    1           2
8      batch9          43.91       Norway  spruce    1           3
9     batch10           9.41       Sweden   birch    0           1
10    batch11          11.10       Sweden   birch    0           2
11    batch12          15.73       Sweden   birch    0           3
12    batch13          16.87  Switzerland   beech    0           1
13    batch14          22.64  Switzerland   beech    0           2
14    batch15          29.75  Switzerland   beech    0           3

def ols_res_grouped(group):
    xcols_const = sm.add_constant(group['Time_steps']) 
    linmod = sm.OLS(group['Concentration'], xcols_const).fit() 
    return linmod.params[1] 

grouped = dat.groupby(['Site','Species','Age']).agg(ols_res_grouped)

```
````

I want to get the regression coefficient of concentration data over Time_steps but get a KeyError: 'Time_steps'. How can the sm method access group["Time_steps"]?

Comment: Please show some sample data for a reproducible model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [pandas's documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation), `agg` applies functions to each column independantly.
It might be possible to use `NamedAgg` but I am not sure.

I think it is a lot easier to just use a for loop for this :

```py
for _, group in dat.groupby(['Site','Species','Age']):
    coeff = ols_res_grouped(group)

    # if you want to put the coeff inside the dataframe
    dat.loc[group.index, 'coeff'] = coeff
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! I still don't understand why my previous code does not work. It just seems to me that agg cannot access a certain column.